# Pasar elementos Listview a un TextView

Tags: java, android

Buenas, en mi codigo tengo un adapter que contiene elementos de mi base de datos, los cuales quiero insertar en textviews de otra actividad (con ids), el problema es que me tira NullPointException, la idea original era pasar directamente los datos del sqlite a lo textview pero no encontre la forma de acceder a los valores de la base de datos, por lo que lo pasé a un array y no funciona, porfavor si alguien sabe como solucionar esto, adjunto codigo. Además tengo la duda sobre cual layout debo desplegar en  setContentView(R.layout.activity_list); (Dado que en activity_horario xml estan creados los text view)
El error surge en Select con el listview.getChild

ListActivity (pasar datos a los textviews)

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);


    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ltvListaEventos);



    BDSQLite bd= new BDSQLite(getApplicationContext(), "Horario", null,1);
    db= bd.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql="select * from Horario";
    Cursor c;
    String ora;
    try {
        c=db.rawQuery(sql,null);
        arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        if(c==null||c.getCount()==0) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No hay eventos disponibles", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }




        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                ora=c.getString(1);
                arrayAdapter.add(ora);
            } while(c.moveToNext());
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

    }catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Error: "+ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.finish();

    }


   // int count = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
    for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i = i + 1)
    {


        String Select= (String) listView.getChildAt(i).toString();
        if (i==0){
            TextView TEXTO11=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t11);
            TEXTO11.setText(Select);


        }




    }


    }
```

error:

```
ava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.marcela.sqlitetet/com.example.marcela.sqlitetet.ListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2193)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at com.example.marcela.sqlitetet.ListActivity.onCreate(ListActivity.java:70)
```

EDIT:

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//al mantener la wea apretada
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_horario);

    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ltvListaEventos);



    BDSQLite bd= new BDSQLite(getApplicationContext(), "Horario", null,1);
    db= bd.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql="select * from Horario";
    Cursor c;
    String ora;
    try {
        c=db.rawQuery(sql,null);
        arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        if(c==null||c.getCount()==0) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No hay eventos disponibles", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }




        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                ora=c.getString(1);
                arrayAdapter.add(ora);
            } while(c.moveToNext());
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

    }catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Error: "+ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.finish();

    }


   int count = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
    for(int i = 0; i <= count; i = i ++)
    {
        if (i==0){
           TextView TEXTO11=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t11);
           TEXTO11.setText(listView.get(i));
        }
    }






}





}
```

Activity horario (tiene los textview, adjunto fragmento del codigo).

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/fila1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/bloque_12"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="7dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/t11"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/t12"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/t13"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/t14"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/t15"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


</TableRow>
```

Horario activity:

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_horario);

    Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton1);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(HORARIOActivity.this, Editar.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: Puedes indicar en el codigo donde exactamente te lanza el error? Eso ayudaria mucho.

Comment: en la parte de String Selector, no encuentro la forma de pasar el contenido del array a textview sin que tire nullpointexeption, de antemano gracias!

Comment: Te refieres en esta parte `var Select = (String) listView.getChildAt(i).toString();`?

Comment: Exacto, el select es el valor que va tomando el array y texto11 el textview al que va dirigido el valor de select, pero no me deja cambiar el valor de TEXTO11, al contrario me tira el error:(

Comment: Y puedes confirmar que `R.id.t11` existe en el layout `activity_list`?

Comment: sisi, confirmado, de hecho es un textview vacío, que debe ser rellenado con la información del listview

Comment: Entonces debe de ser la variable `Select` que se le esta asignando null. Puedes confirmarlo?

Comment: Si, me dice que esa línea esta tirando el error

Comment: He probado cambiar la variable a string, texview, y nada, nullpointexeption

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info) Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Answer (score 0):

En vez que utilizar `listView.getChildAt(i).toString();` Intenta crear un array que contendra los elementos de la base de datos:

```
//...
Cursor c;
String ora;
ArrayList<String> datos = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
  //...
```

Ahora, cuando obtengas los datos desde la base de datos lo agregas a la lista:

```
//...

if(c.moveToFirst()){
    do {
        ora=c.getString(1);
        arrayAdapter.add(ora);

        //agregamos el elemento al array
        datos.add(ora)
    } while(c.moveToNext());
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

//...
```

Entonces ahora solo tendrías acceder a los elementos utilizando el metodo get() de la lista:

```
//...
for(int = 0; i < datos.size(); i++)
{

    if (i==0){
        TextView TEXTO11=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t11);

        // le asigamos el texto al TEXT11
        TEXTO11.setText(datos.get(i));
    }
}

//...
```

Codigo completo del metodo `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_horario);

    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ltvListaEventos);


    BDSQLite bd= new BDSQLite(getApplicationContext(), "Horario", null,1);
    db= bd.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql="select * from Horario";
    Cursor c;
    String ora;
    ArrayList<String> datos = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        c=db.rawQuery(sql,null);
        arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        if(c==null||c.getCount()==0) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No hay eventos disponibles", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                ora=c.getString(1);
                arrayAdapter.add(ora);

                // agregas los datos al array
                datos.add(ora)
            } while(c.moveToNext());
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

    }catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Error: "+ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.finish();

    }


    int count = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
    for(int i = 0; i <= datos.size(); i = i ++)
    {
        if (i==0){
           TextView TEXTO11=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t11);
           TEXTO11.setText(datos.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, me quedaron unas dudas, datos es el nombre de la lista?, me sale "Cannot resolve method get(int)" cuando lo escribo usando datos como nombre de la lista, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Si, es el nombre de la lista que se muestra en el ejemplo declarad arriba.

Comment: Gracias y como resuelvo el cannot resolve method get(int)?

Comment: Seguro que declarares la variable datos como ArrayList<String>? el metodo get() pertence esa tipo de dato.

Comment: No me funciona:(, lo he usado pero al cambiar String por int, no me funciona el codigo

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agregalo como lo pusiste para darle una mirada. Recuerda escribirme cuando lo hagas.

Comment: ahí lo edite, no se como arreglarlo:(

Comment: Lo dejaste igual. No agregaste lo que te indique en mi respuesta. No veo la varaible datos de tipo ArrayList<String>. Lo hiciste o prefieres que edite tu codigo y lo agregue completo de como deberia de ser?

Comment: Si es posible te lo agradecería demasiado!, estoy muy necesitado es lo único que me falta para terminar con mi proyecto:(

Comment: Deben haber 2 arrays entonces?

Comment: Ya esta editado. Agregue solo el codigo del metodo onCreate. Reemplazalo y listo.

Comment: no me funciono:(, tiene algo que ver el setcontent de arriba que tiene 2 parámetros juntos?

Comment: No me habia fijado en eso. Claro que tiene que ver. Utiliza el que tenga la vista donde eesta el text11

Comment: lo usé y no lo edita al parecer, y si agrego un boton que vaya a la lista, sale el error de boundexeption:(, adjunto las otras activities

Comment: O lo otro como podría llevar directamente los datos de la base de datos directamente a los textview??

Answer (score 0):

cuando lo muestras en un listview seria algo asi ;
ArrayAdapteradapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arregle);
ListView lista=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.Lista);
lista.setAdapter(adapter);

pero si quieres mostrarlo en un textview borras ese codigo y en tu ciclo do if
le agregas

mtextmostrar.setText(datos);